# Can you time travel to get contacts?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've already done my hair and i time travelled more than 2 weeks. Why won't it let me buy contacts?

Comment: This question doesn't seem very clear or thoughtful.

Answer (score -1):

In order to buy the contacts, you will need to get several hairstyles